# Move the tableview according to indexPath.row

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, tableview

I have a horizontal tableview and i would like to move this tableview and position the cell according to the  indexPath.row that i give in the middle of my view.

I'm trying to find the method but cannot find it :(

Could you help me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```